# Should action be taken over copied Stack Overflow content on another site?

Tags: discussion

I've found a copy of Stack Overflow at another website.

SO: [Vertical Custom Scrollbars with JqueryTools RangeInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952654/vertical-custom-scrollbars-with-jquerytools-rangeinput)

Other Site: http://cloudbings.com/questions/1551711/vertical-custom-scrollbars-with-jquerytools-rangeinput

This is a verbatim copy. Does SO takes an action over such websites or anyone can use without declaring resources?

---

Or, I think the author who posted q/a in SO, posted the same in his website? Is it allowable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the *site* copies all or a lot of content from SO, you should see this post on MSE regarding content scrapers: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177). It explains the procedure you have to follow to report content scrapers to the SE team so they can take action.

If the *content author* is the one posting on both sides, there is actually no point in prohibiting this. Why should this be disallowed? I can't think of any valid reason.

Comment: Thanks. I've submitted a report.